# Arduino 1.0.5 I can not select board

Tags: arduino

Hi I have download Arduino 1.0.5 I have installed the Micro drive , I am able to view some serial input from the micro on the serial monitor. This micro was programmed by friend.

When i try and select board, the menu does not open a selection for me why?

What do i still need to do?

I am using XP and i am able to select the serial port.

Comment: what OS are you using? Did you select the serial port?

Comment: Yes i did, and using XP

Comment: if you can't select a board, your installation of the arduino IDE, is corrupted, have you tried to reinstall the arduino IDE, if so try an older version of the IDE

Comment: Onatom you are right , my friend gave a folder he had installed to on his PC, told me it work just like that! New install and it works!

Comment: next time secure-remove the usb :)